# Mysql how to get percentage by sum of months for customer?

Tags: mysql

I am using sql query to get percentage of declined order_ value of two months from my customer table. But this query just doing total by month.

```
select extract(MONTH from timestamp) as month,sum(order_value) as total_value 
from customer_order 
group by month;
```

e.g. is

```
declined%=((sumofjanmonthorder_value-sumoffebmonthorder_value) /sum of jan month order_value) * 100
```

```
order_id    customer_id order_value timestamp
101         501         25080.50    2020-09-0110:00:00
102         502         12055.00    2020-09-1212:00:00
103         503         1500.50     2020-09-2516:00:00
104         502         1005.00     2020-10-0512:00:00
105         501         1200.00     2020-10-1816:00:00
106         503         15000.00    2020-10-3016:00:00
```

Comment: Provide the table with sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (textual, code-formatted). Provide desired output for this sample data with explanations. Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: I have attached sample table screenshot and phpmyadmin version is 5.0

Comment: We do not heal by photos.

Comment: i have added sample data, currently i have added this data manually in db not using any insert query